# Confused regarding cross product of vectors

Tags: vectors

Recently going through one of the questions , it's said that |a×b.c|=|a||b||c| but the thing here is I'm confused regarding the product, which one should i do?
● I thought of doing |(a×b).c| but then shouldn't they are supposed to put brackets in question there ? 
● and i thought doing (b.c) first but then i realised its give just magnitude and we can't cross it with a then . Is I'm thinking correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thankyou , I'll consider it from next time .

Answer (score 1):

You've figured out correctly that the brackets are unnecessary since RHS is a scalar, so that (under usual interpretation), the product $a×(b\cdot c)$ is not defined, since then you'd be dotting a vector and a scalar.

So, in fact, you have that $a×b\cdot c$ should be taken to mean $(a×b)\cdot c,$ unless otherwise excepted.

Comment: Yeah Thanks allawonder , i just thought they should supposed to put that bracket or may be it's a printing mistake or might be they just want you to already know this thing

Comment: @VishalKumar The answer is in your last clause, as I also said in the above answer. They assume that you should know that that is the only reasonable interpretation.